# How do I fill a cell in an Excel document with a custom format

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a job where I have to fill in on an Excel sheet at what times I have worked and I need to upload that file to a dropbox map. I would like to make a program which does this for me automatically. Uploading of files to dropbox is working now but I want to change the cells in my Excel file via my java application.
Here is my java code:

```
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("name.xls");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row= sheet.getRow(7);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
    String week = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
    cell.setCellValue("18:00"); 
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("name.xls");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```

I can fill the cell with 18:00 but the problem is that the format of the cell is custom. When I look at the custom format, it says it uses `[u]:mm`. When I fill in 18:00 it puts 18:00 in the cell, but it remains on the left side of the cell instead of the right, so I suppose that the format isn't correct. So my question is, how do I correctly fill a cell with a custom format.

Comment: Of course, you are putting a string `"18:00"` into the cell. You should use the `setValueCell(Date d)` method.

Comment: But according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html I can't use any of the mehtods and I need to use the Calendar class. But Cell.getDateCellValue() returns a Date object. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Apache POI documentation on custom formats](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#DataFormats)

To set a cell to hold the time `18:00`, then what you should do is

```
// Format to hold a time
DataFormat format = wb.createDataFormat();
CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("HH:MM"));

// Set the cell to hold 18:00 and style
Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(18.0/24.0);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Times in Excel are fractions of a whole day, so for 18:00 you need to set `(18/24)`, then apply the time style to it

Alternately, create a Java Date object, and set that, if it's easier

Comment: The cell had more styling to it so I had te define it all but I got it to work.